# Is $H = \{ z \in G \mid o(z) < \infty \}$ a subgroup of $G=(\Bbb C^*,\cdot)$?

Tags: group-theory

> Consider $G = ( \Bbb C^* , \cdot)$ and  $H = \{ z \in G \mid o(z) \; \text{is finite} \}$ . Will $H$ be a subgroup of $G$?

The lecture I'm referring to says that this will be a subgroup of $G$. All elements having modulus $1$ are of finite order, however, if I take  $(1/\sqrt{2}+(1/\sqrt{2})i)$ and $(1/\sqrt{2} -(1/\sqrt{2})i)$ , they both belong to H but their sum doesn't.

So is my conclusion accurate that $H$ will not be a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Yes..It is a subgroup...,called torsion subgroup..!

Comment: @ChinnapparajR I didn't know that name. Thanks a lot, for the edit also.

Answer (score 2):

You are right the sum is not in $H$. But the group operation in question is multiplication of complex numbers, not addition.

It is true that $H = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} : z \text{ has finite  order} \}$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}, \cdot)$. Checking this is a straightforward exercise.

Comment: I can't believe I asked this question. Thanks a lot for pointing out that I don't need to add them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [one-step subgroup test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_test#:%7E:text=In%20abstract%20algebra%2C%20the%20one,is%20also%20in%20the%20subset.).

Since $o(i)=4$, we have $i\in H$. Hence $H\neq\varnothing$.

By definition, $H\subseteq G=(\Bbb C^*,\cdot)$.

Let $x,y\in H$. Then $m=o(x), n=o(y)$ are both finite. Now

$$\begin{align}
(xy^{-1})^{mn}&= x^{mn}(y^{-1})^{mn}\\
&=(x^m)^n(y^{-n})^m\\
&=1^n1^m\\
&=1,
\end{align}$$

so that $o( xy^{-1})$ divides $mn$. But $mn$ is finite. Hence $o(xy^{-1})$ is finite. Hence $xy^{-1}\in H$.

Hence $H\le G$.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that $1 \in H$, and by the definition of $H$ we have $ H \subset \mathbb{C}^*$. 
For all $x$ in $H$ we denote the order of $x$ by $o(x)$.
Let $x, y \in H$, we have
$$ (xy)^{o(x) o(y)}=x^{o(x) o(y)}y^{o(x) o(y)}\\ =(x^{o(x)})^{ o(y)}(y^{o(y)})^{o(x)}\\ =1^{ o(y)}1^{o(x)}\\ =1$$
then $xy \in H$. 
Let $x \in H$ and let $x^{-1}$ be the inverse element of $x$ in $ (\mathbb{C}^*,.)$, we have
$$1=1^{o(x)}=(xx^{-1})^{o(x)}=x^{o(x)}(x^{-1})^{o(x)}=1(x^{-1})^{o(x)}=(x^{-1})^{o(x)}$$.
then $x^{-1} \in H$. 
Hence, $H$ is a subgroup of $ (\mathbb{C}^*,.)$.

Comment: You need to make clear that $H\subseteq (\Bbb C^*,\cdot)$.

Comment: @Shaun it holds by the definition of $H$

Comment: Yes, I know, but it needs stating, @AhmedBachir.

Comment: @Shaun thanks I will add it.